# Communication with opened window on Android after allowing popups

Tags: javascript, android-chrome

I have a web application which opens a window via JavaScript's `window.open()` function call and monitors the opened window. This correctly causes the "popup's blocked - enable" notification in browsers, but in the case of Chrome on Android, once the "allow" button is pressed, it opens the window anyway - other browsers do not appear to do anything.

The problem lies as `window.open()` has already returned `null` (correctly in my opinion), this prevents the parent window from checking whether the child window has been closed (among other events). I have tried calling `window.open()` on setInterval to try an detect when a user allows popups, but that causes chrome to keeps showing "x popups blocked".

My question is how can I get the (correct) result of `window.open()` once the popup has been opened (after a user clicks the "allow popup button").

Comment: Did you have any luck? I'm running into a similar issue on Desktop and would love a way to know if the child window was closed prematurely.

Comment: I haven't revisited it for some time, but would probably have the same issue. If you're successfully getting the result of `window.open()`, then keeping an eye on that should help you.

Comment: Yea I couldn't find a way around it so instead I ended up with two solutions. First if the result of window.open is not null then you're fine. If it is null, use the document's cookie to communicate between the two pages (since they are on the same domain). Not pretty but it works I guess :-). Thanks!